# Finding an Equivalence Relation from a Partition?

Tags: relations

I've been looking around and found questions related to deriving partitions from equivalence relations; however I was wondering if there is a method to finding an equivalence relation from a given partition.

For example the partition $\{\{1, ..., 9\},\{10, ..., 99\},\{100, ..., 999\}, ...\}$ of the natural numbers (not counting 0). The best I can come up with (by guessing) for an equivalence relation is $x{R}y$ iff [$x$ and $y$ have the same number of digits], but that doesn't seem very mathematical. Otherwise my second best guess is something to do with logarithms. (Full disclosure, this is a homework problem.)

So I was wondering, is there a method to derive an equivalence relation based on the equivalence classes set by the partition?

Comment: A partition defines an equivalence relation. a~b if a and b are in the same partition. It is a good exercise to prove that statement.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yep and vice versa. The full story is: an equivalence relation $R$ determines a partition $P_R$, a partition $P$ determines an equivalence relation $R_P$, and these are inverses of each other: $R_{P_R} = R$ ("the equivalence relation determined by the partition induced by an equivalence relation is the original equivalence relation"), and similarly $P_{R_P} = P$ for a partition. It's a very good exercise to work out the details. Once. (It's not hard, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same number of decimal digits sounds good to me.

To make it harder to understand, we could write $x\sim y$ if $\lfloor \log_{10} x\rfloor=\lfloor \log_{10} y\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! But I am also wondering about generally finding an equivalence relation from a partition (other than listing out all the ordered pairs from the equivalence classes). My example probably wasn't the best; what about for example $\{..., \{-2\}, \{-1\}, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3, 4, 5, ...\}\}$ on the integers? I'm not sure how I would go about defining the equivalence relation for that partition.

Comment: Equivalence relation and partition are essentially the same. One can go seamlessly from one to the other. The only issue, a not  very interesting one, is expressing the relation, or the partition, in a compact way.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I assumed that all relations could be expressed neatly (which doesn't make much sense at all). I will just have to list the ordered pairs of the relation then. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In a reasonably precise sense of most (cardinality) most relations cannot be expressed neatly. But many important relations  can be.